# C# 2d array value replace

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I've created an array like this:

```
int[,] grid = new int[9, 9];

        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        var rowLength = grid.GetLength(0);
        var colLength = grid.GetLength(1);
        for (int row = 0; row < rowLength; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < colLength; col++)
            {
                grid[row, col] = randomNumber.Next(6);


            }

        }
```

This will result in an 2d array 9x9 which is filled with random numbers. 
example:

5   5   0   0   4   3   3   4   5
2   0   5   5   2   1   2   0   4
4   0   2   0   2   4   3   5   4
0   3   4   3   1   2   4   1   1
5   4   1   3   3   0   4   3   4
0   2   3   3   1   2   0   1   5
2   4   3   1   2   5   4   3   1
0   4   5   3   1   1   0   3   1
2   1   2   2   2   4   0   3   2

Now comes the real question: How can I make the zeros "disappear"(the zeros would be replaced with the values above them, or the zeros would move up against the top)? Obviously the zeros at the top row do not have any values above them so there would have to be created a new random number. Also randomNumber.Next(6)+1 is not an option this time around. 
I have tried this,but to no use:

```
 foreach(int z in grid)
        {
        if(z==0)
        {
        if(col>0)
        {
        int a=grid[col,row];
        int b=grid[col-1,row];
        a=b;
        b=a;



        }
        else
        {
            int a = grid[col, row];
        Random randomNumber= new Random();
        a = randomNumber.Next(6) + 1;
        }



        }
        }
```

EDIT:
Example in a 3x3:
initial grid:

1 3 5

0 5 3

3 4 0

after:

R 3 R

1 5 5

3 4 3

R=new randomNumber which is not 0

Comment: Do you want to create matrix without zeores? Or you want to write a method that checks matrix and removes zeroes?

Comment: Alternative b, a method that checks matrix and removes zeroes @Romansz

Comment: No, he's basically writing Tetris.  He needs to get the value from the row above when he clears a 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I briefly tested this, and it appears to do what you want:

```
        int[,] grid = new int[3, 3];

        grid[0, 0] = 1;
        grid[0, 1] = 2;
        grid[0, 2] = 3;
        grid[1, 0] = 0;
        grid[1, 1] = 5; 
        grid[1, 2] = 6; 
        grid[2, 0] = 0;
        grid[2, 1] = 8; 
        grid[2, 2] = 9;

        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        var rowLength = grid.GetLength(0);
        var colLength = grid.GetLength(1);

        //for (int row = 0; row < rowLength; row++)
        //{
        //    for (int col = 0; col < colLength; col++)
        //    {
        //        grid[row, col] = randomNumber.Next(6);
        //        if (row == 1 && col == 0)
        //            grid[row, col] = 0;
        //        if (row == 2 && col == 0)
        //            grid[row, col] = 0;
        //    }
        //}

        //  Now, we have the grid with 0's, time to play Tetris with the 0's.
        for (int row = rowLength - 1; row >= 0; row--)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < colLength; col++)
            {
                if (grid[row, col] == 0)
                {
                    for (int currentRow = row; currentRow >= 0; currentRow--)
                    {
                        if (currentRow == 0)
                            grid[currentRow, col] = randomNumber.Next(1, 6);
                        else
                        {
                            grid[currentRow, col] = grid[currentRow - 1, col];
                            if (grid[currentRow, col] == 0)  //  There was a 0 above our 0.
                            {
                                bool replaced = false;
                                for (int numberOfRowsAbove = 1; numberOfRowsAbove <= currentRow; numberOfRowsAbove++)
                                {
                                    if (grid[currentRow - numberOfRowsAbove, col] != 0)
                                    {
                                        grid[currentRow, col] = grid[currentRow - numberOfRowsAbove, col];
                                        replaced = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (!replaced)
                                    grid[currentRow, col] = randomNumber.Next(1, 6);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Random.Next(6)+1 would work as well, but because each time something gets removed on the grid the new value for the removed object is going to be zero, then the numbers above the removed object would drop one or more rows down.

Comment: In this code there is one problem... one value seems to be different from the expected... Otherwise it works perfectly.

Comment: First grid:
553231504 
500321133 
223302143 
113413405 
003504014 
440335433 
224004334 
015351202 
521435330

Comment: your method:

134441355 
134441355 
134342153 
523343133 
213424445 
143515414 
424334333 
215351234 
521435332

Comment: I edited again.  If there is a 0 in the row above a 0, you have to deal with that fact as well.

Comment: Expected would be this: 134441355
134341554
134342153
523343133
213424445
143515414
424334333
215351234
521435332

Comment: Please try with 3 x 3.  9 x 9 is too much trouble to try to follow.   Give an example of failure on a 3 x 3.  Make sure to run my new code that deals with stacked 0's atop other 0's.

Comment: your method vs expected: check the second rows last value on both, 5 instead of 4...

Comment: this problem doesn't occur on a 3x3 but perhaps on a 4x4

Comment: I don't know how you are getting that result from my code.  I tested your input, and I get this out:  1 2 5 2,  5 4 5 3,  4 2 2 5,  4 4 5 4

Comment: initial:
4224 
0523 
1452 
3120

your:
4224 
4524 
1453 
3122 
expected: 
R22R 
4524 
1453 
3122

Comment: Sorry I don't know what I do right now... But it seems that in a 9x9 grid i don't get what i expect

Comment: Are you sure you know what to expect?  I tried your 4 x 4, and you said it was wrong.  But it was right.  Unless you have some other rule in mind that you did not disclose....

Comment: Finally I got the problem recreated in 4x4... initial 
0114 
0230 
0512 
4043

your:
1142 
1132 
1212 
4543

expected:
RR1R 
R134 
R212 
4543

check the last column on expected and yours

Comment: I recommend that you open these up in notepad or whatever, that way it becomes easier...

Comment: I tested your 4 x 4, and the result is:  1511,  3134,  1212,  4543.   This is correct.   I re-edited my code to take care of when there is 1 zero above another 0.  Are you using it?   See that your code is the same as mine above.

Comment: I found my problem, it was not in your method but in my project... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this is what you want : **(the zeros would be replaced with the values above them, or the zeros would move up against the top)**

```
    int[,] grid = new int[9, 9];
    Random randomNumber = new Random();
    var rowLength = grid.GetLength(0);
    var colLength = grid.GetLength(1);
    for (int row = 0; row < rowLength; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < colLength; col++)
        {
            grid[row, col] = randomNumber.Next(6);
            if(grid[row,col) == 0)
            {
                if(row == 0)
                {
                    while(true)
                    {
                       grid[row,col] = randomNumber.Next(6);
                       if(grid[row,col] == 0)
                          continue;
                       else
                          break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    grid[row,col] = grid[row-1,col];
                }
            }                 
        }

    }
```

Edit : Sorry, I checked to code after you show me output and realised that I forgot to check if the entry is equal to 0 or not :)

Comment: this clears the grid of the zeros, but instead makes each row the same, like this:

111314532

 
111314532

 
111314532

 
111314532

 
111314532

 
111314532

 
111314532

 
111314532

 
111314532

Comment: Looks to me like the idea in the code above is on the right track, but that you need to call it as a method and call it recursively to get all the other rows above to also update with the values of the rows above those.   Set it up and recurse it.

Comment: UPDATE: this does 50% of what I asked for, this generates new randomnumber for each 0 in the top row, but then it copies the top row to all the other rows...

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are looking to get a `Random` number between 1 and 6?

For that you can use the [Random.Next(int minValue, int maxValue)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
Random randomNumber = new Random();
randomNumer.Next(1, 6);
```

Also, when working with random you should never re-seed inside of the loop. Instantiate the `Random` object before the loop, then use it. Your first example was good, but not the second one.

Comment: Random.Next(6)+1 would work as well, but because each time something gets removed on the grid the new value for the removed object is going to be zero, then the numbers above the removed object would drop one or more rows down.